# gdb: set breakpoint in specific library

Tags: c, gdb, shared-libraries, dlopen

Let's say I have a file called library.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
void someFunc(int n)
{
    printf("%s: %d\n", LIBNAME, n);
}
```

I compile it into two shared object files, using different macros (so resulting code is different). In this example I provide different LIBNAME:

```
gcc -DLIBNAME=\"lib1\" -fPIC -shared -g -Og library.c -o library1.so
gcc -DLIBNAME=\"lib2\" -fPIC -shared -g -Og library.c -o library2.so
```

Then I load both libraries from executable:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (*functype)(int);

int callFunc(const char* libname, int n)
{
    void* lib = dlopen(libname, RTLD_NOW|RTLD_LOCAL);
    if (!lib) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
        return -1;
    }
    functype func = dlsym(lib, "someFunc");
    if (!func) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
        dlclose(lib);
        return -1;
    }
    func(n);
    dlclose(lib);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int res = callFunc("./library1.so", 42);
    if (res == 0)
        return callFunc("./library2.so", 13);
    else
        return res;
}
```

In gdb I want to debug function from a certain library (e.g. library1.so), while not having to worry about another one (library2.so). I can't set breakpoint by function name, because it's the same in both libraries. I can't do it with sourcefile:linenumber either, since source file is the same for both libraries. How can I tell gdb to set breakpoint only in one library?

Answer (score 1):

> In gdb I want to debug function from a certain library (e.g.
>   library1.so), while not having to worry about another one (library2.so)

You can set pending breakpoint on `someFunc` and ignore it manually if it was called from `library2.so`. You can know this from `info sharedlibrary` output: if `someFunc` was called from `library2.so`, `library2.so` will be loaded and you will see it in `info sharedlibrary` output.

```
(gdb) info sharedlibrary 
From                To                  Syms Read   Shared Object Library
0x00007ffff7dd6f60  0x00007ffff7df5030  Yes (*)     /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
0x00007ffff7bd2ee0  0x00007ffff7bd3bbe  Yes (*)     /lib64/libdl.so.2
0x00007ffff7834340  0x00007ffff797b27f  Yes (*)     /lib64/libc.so.6
0x00007ffff7611550  0x00007ffff761162c  Yes         ./library2.so
(*): Shared library is missing debugging information.
(gdb)
```

When you see it loaded, you can ignore this breakpoint and continue execution. Though it is not fully automated way of debugging `someFunc`, this is probably the best you can do in this case.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use "break if"? Something like

```
break library.c:<line_no> if libname == "./library1.so"
```

In case libname does not work, you can also use the second parameter n.

Comment: Do you mean compare to libname argument of callFunc? I just provided a simple example. In real project it would have much deeper call stack. Also libname is not visible in someFunc. Can I somehow break if on binary name?